# Install a file that.gz

Tags: software-installation

Hello I am new on Ubuntu yesterday I try install a USB modem internet and when I open it it give me a tar.gz file . After I extract it with the file manager by default on Ubuntu and the file is on the desktop but what to do next ?
Can someone tell me the code I have to write or something ?
I think the USB can configure on Ubuntu because when I first open it it show me 3 options : windows ,Mac, Linux

Comment: A .tar.gz file is simply a compressed file. It could be anything - photos, videos, applications. Any .tar.gz file should have instructions (like a README.txt  or INSTALL.txt file) to tell you how to decompress the file(s) and how to install the decompressed file(s). There are many possible ways to install such a file - it depends upon what the file does. There's also a chance that nothing needs to be installed at all, and that your Ubuntu system will properly recognize the device without you needing to take any action.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see nothing like readme . The only thing that seem to be install is a file type executable but when I press run nothing happens

Comment: Thank you for the help the problem was I need to write the internet provider name .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might sound silly, but have you tried simply sticking the USB modem and giving it a try? In my case, Ubuntu recognized my Huawei and the only thing I needed to do was to go to the top-right menu (next to the power icon) and activate the connection.

Comment: Let's try something different - could you paste the link from which you have downloaded the tar.gz file? I will have a look at the files, maybe there is an executable script somewhere in there :-)

Comment: Yeaa you were right It did not need me to install nothing . The problem was that I did not write the name of the provider on the modem list so it was blocking internet access . Thank you very much

Comment: There is a executable file but did not run when I press it

Comment: I'm happy it worked!

Comment: Have a great day

Comment: Could you take a moment to mark the question as answered?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers